# Run multiple commands through Ant exec

Tags: ant

I want to do this through an Ant build script:

```
$ /bin/sh
$ cd /path/to/executable
$ ./executable.sh
```

This is what I tried but I think it only executes the `cd` command:

```
<exec executable="/bin/sh" os="Mac OS X">
    <arg value="-c"/>
    <arg value="cd /path/to/executable"/>
    <arg value="./executable.sh"/>
</exec>
```

I am on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Only the first arg after the `-c` is run by the shell, hence the behaviour you see.  Just put the two commands into one arg, separated by a semicolon:

```
<exec executable="/bin/sh" os="Mac OS X">
    <arg value="-c"/>
    <arg value="cd /path/to/executable; ./executable.sh"/>
</exec>
```

Comment: This is strange, which means we cant use the args for Mac? Do we need to give all the command in the same line next to -c args?

Comment: I would have suggested instead to  run each command in its own exec  tag. Chaining them like that obfuscates errors. Should one of them fail, you might not get the necessary error with which to identify the culprit.

Comment: @luis - true, but the second command in this case appears to requite the chaining.