# Using <java> tag in Apach Ant, can I run both Server and the ProxyServer class

Tags: java, ant, proxy, antlr, build-tools

I would like to start Server and the ProxyServer class simultaneously, using Ant  tag, is it possible to run the wo classes?

Here is the code I tried but Ant only starts the Server class and does not do anything there after, not sure if there is away in ant to achieve this.

Appreciate your help.

```
<target name="pxyServer" depends="server">
    <echo>Executing Target - Run ProxyServer</echo>
    <java classname="pxy.ProxyServer">
        <classpath path="staging" />
    </java>
</target>

<target name="server">
    <echo>Executing Target - RunServer</echo>
    <java classname="pxy.Server">
        <classpath path="staging" />
    </java>
</target>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your targets are executed sequentially, and since the first one keeps running, the second one never gets the chance to start.

For parallel execution, you can use ant's "parallel" task:
http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/parallel.html

Your modified script should probably look something like this:

```xml
<target name="startServerAndProxy">
    <echo>Running server and proxy...</echo>
    <parallel>
        <java classname="pxy.Server">
            <classpath path="staging" />
        </java>
        <java classname="pxy.ProxyServer">
            <classpath path="staging" />
        </java>
    </parallel>
</target>
```

(Of course, if you're trying to start some third application in parallel, a client for example, then you should also include that one in the "parallel".)

UPDATE:

To start the server and the proxy each in its own console, I don't know if it can be done with the "java" Ant task, but I just tested that it can be done with "exec":

```xml
<target name="doit">
    <parallel>
        <exec executable="cmd" dir="staging">
            <arg line="/k start java.exe pxy.Server"/>
        </exec>
        <exec executable="cmd" dir="staging">
            <arg line="/k start java.exe pxy.ProxyServer"/>
        </exec>
    </parallel>
</target>
```

Comment: Hi Andrei, Firstly many thanks for the help, it works.  However is it possible to spawn it as a separate process so each class can have its own console.

Comment: Hi Bees, glad it helped, to be able to use decent formatting I added the reply to your second question as an update to the original answer.

Comment: Hi Andrei, Thanks for the update, however I couldn't try that as I use MAC, any clue how to start the Terminal Services Window on Mac.

Comment: Hi Bees, using Ant exec on a Mac is exemplified here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970564/run-multiple-commands-through-ant-exec